# Dynamically update plane / cube vertices using threejs - issue while updating matrix

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a plane, which is added to the scene using threejs. I am adjusting position & rotation using User Interface controls , if there is a change in position or in rotation then I am running below code to get updated plane / cube vertices & Matrix Values:

```
plane.updateMatrixWorld();
plane.updateMatrix(); 
plane.geometry.applyMatrix( plane.matrix );
plane.matrix.identity();
console.log(plane.matrix); // using this to get matrix values
console.log(plane.geometry.vertices); //using this to get plane vertices.
```

When I am running above code facing issue in position shift for the plane / cube / mesh in the scene.

Tried adding below code to make it dynamic updates to vertices but it did not work:

```
plane.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
plane.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
plane.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
plane.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
plane.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
plane.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
plane.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;
```

---

Yes, Got the solution,When there is a change in position/rotation call below code.
     
      `var plane_vector;
      function updateVertices(){
          plane.updateMatrixWorld();
          console.log("plane Vertices: ");
          for(i = 0; i<=(plane.geometry.vertices.length-1); i++){
              plane_vector[i] = 
              plane.geometry.vertices[i].clone();
              plane_vector[i].applyMatrix4( 
              plane.matrixWorld );
          }
          console.log(plane.matrix);
      }`

Comment: No, not related. Thankyou. Removed php from the post.

Comment: I realize this question was posed almost a year ago, but I was wondering if you ever found an answer to this? I am having a similar issue with ThreeJs.  When I update the vertices of my plane I expect the physics of objects on the plane to update as well. Using Physijs as my physics engine.

Comment: Yes, Got the solution,When there is a change in position/rotation call this function.
    var plane_vector;
    function updateVertices(){
       plane.updateMatrixWorld();
       console.log("plane Vertices: ");
       for(i = 0; i<=(plane.geometry.vertices.length-1); i++){
          plane_vector[i] = 
          plane.geometry.vertices[i].clone();
          plane_vector[i].applyMatrix4( 
          plane.matrixWorld );
         }
       console.log(plane.matrix);
    }